# Kivy Clock.schedule.interval()'s callback() execution issue

Tags: callback, kivy, clock

I am not sure the question title is suitable, my issue is that when I run a time countdown code using the Kivy Clock.schedule.interval(callback, 0), in the callback function after completing the time countdown, it may not display the new setting countdown value. My code is as following steps

1. In each callback running, the countdown value (tm) will decrease the dt (get from Clock.schedule.interval())
2. When the countdown value is equal less than zero (tm<=0), then reset the countdown value to the initial value
3. To check the reset countdown value, I use the print() to show the countdown value, it shows the correct value
4. To set an ObjectProperty passes the countdown value to .kv file and display the countdown value in a label
5. The label always shows the correct countdown value before the countdown is completed.
6. When the countdown completed it will reset the countdown value to initial value, before restart the countdown, I use a for loop to delay the countdown restarting
7. In the delay duration, the label always shows the countdown value as zero

My question is why in the delay duration the label always shows the its value (text) as zero, I should already reset the countdown value to its initial value.

My code is as follows,
in the .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from time import strftime

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class ClockTest(BoxLayout):    
    time_str = ObjectProperty()
    tm_interval = 5     # 5 seconds
    tm_flag = True
    tm = tm_interval

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ClockTest, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.cb, 0)
        
    def cb(self, dt):
        if self.tm_flag:
            self.tm -= dt
            if self.tm <= 0:
                self.tm = self.tm_interval          
                print('tm: ', self.tm)
                m, s = divmod(self.tm, 60)
                self.time_str.text = ('%02d:%02d.%02d' %
                    (int(m), int(s), int(s * 100 % 100)))
                print('time_str: ',self.time_str.text)
            
                # loop: for time delay 
                for x in range(100000):
                    text = strftime('[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S')

        m, s = divmod(self.tm, 60)
        self.time_str.text = ('%02d:%02d.%02d' %
            (int(m), int(s), int(s * 100 % 100)))
    
    
class ClockTest1App(App):
    def build(self):
        tm_obj = Test()
    
        return tm_obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClockTest1App().run()
```

in the .kv file

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

Test:

<ClockTest>:
    time_str: time_str

    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        id: time_str
        font_size: 40
        bold: True
        text: time_str.text 

<Test>:    
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'ClockTest'
        font_size: 15
        ClockTest:
```

In the code it should not have logical issue, I do not know what is the problem, please help me to solve it, thanks!

Another question is that how I can improve the time delay code, if use the time sleep it will block the code and shows the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in this issue I have two questions:

1. When I want to use the 'for loop' to display the reset time value in a short period, why does it always show the last time value - value zero (before the time reset) during the loop running?
2. How can I display the reset time value in a time period before the time countdown again?

Now I can solve the second issue, but I still do not know why the 'for loop' delay code does not work.

For displaying the reset time value in a time period before time countdown again, I update the .py file as below,

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from time import strftime

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class ClockTest(BoxLayout):    
    time_str = ObjectProperty()
    tm_interval = 5     # 5 seconds
    tm_flag = True
    tm = tm_interval

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ClockTest, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.cb, 0)
    
    def delayset(self, cb, dt):
        Clock.schedule_once(cb, dt)
        
    def delaycb(self, dt):
        self.tm_flag = True
    
    def cb(self, dt):
        if self.tm_flag:
            self.tm -= dt
            if self.tm <= 0:
                self.tm = self.tm_interval          
                print('tm: ', self.tm)
                self.tm_flag = False
                self.delayset(self.delaycb, 3)                
            
        m, s = divmod(self.tm, 60)
        self.time_str.text = ('%02d:%02d.%02d' %
            (int(m), int(s), int(s * 100 % 100)))


class ClockTest1App(App):
    def build(self):
        tm_obj = Test()
        return tm_obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClockTest1App().run()
```